# Turn on keyboard backlight from multi-user.target

Tags: cron, multiuser, keyboard-backlight

Is there a way to turn on the keyboard backlight from the multi-user.target environment? As X11 is not loaded, the command `xset led on` does not work and gives `xset: unable to open display ""`.

Currently, I am wanting the keyboard backlight to turn on each time the system starts (only if the keyboard is present). I would also like the keyboard backlight to turn on regardless the system loading in a graphical or non-graphical environment. Preferably, I would like this done through Cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `setleds`, which acts on the current virtual terminal (without using X):

```
setleds +num +caps +scroll
```

You can set the VT defaults with the `-D` flag. If standard input isn’t a VT, you can redirect it:

```
setleds +num +caps +scroll < /dev/tty1
```

(assuming you can write to `/dev/tty1`).

Comment: `setleds +scroll` turned on the keyboard light and the ScrollLock light along with ScrollLock itself. When applying the `-D` flag and rebooting, the VT defaults did not persist as all three were set to off (along with the keyboard light). Writing to `/dev/tty1` did not make this persist either.

Comment: Ah, are you talking about backlight LEDs rather than the three indicator LEDs? What type of keyboard do you have? (`setleds -D` doesn’t set boot-time defaults, just defaults during the current session.)

Comment: To clarify, I am talking about the backlight LED. I am using the [Cooler Master Devastator II SGB-3031-KKMF1-US](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/peripheral/keyboards/devastator-ii/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `systemd` service that starts once upon bootup:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/setleds.service
```

Then type the contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run setleds once at startup
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setleds +num +caps +scroll
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If that doesn't work and you need the input redirection, just change the relevant line:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/setleds +num +caps +scroll < /dev/tty1'
```

And to make sure it runs:

```
sudo systemctl enable setleds.service
sudo systemctl start setleds.service
```

Alternatively you can use `cron` instead:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then, add the following:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/setleds +num +caps +scroll < /dev/tty1
```

PS Whoa, I didn't know my keyboard had a backlight... Scroll Lock seems to turn it on!